# How to unwrinkle leather?

Tags: cleaning, home, clothing, personal-care

I have an old vintage jacket that's been sitting in a box for a long time and there are some pretty serious wrinkles/creases all over the jacket. Is there a way to get out the wrinkles safely without damaging the leather or color? Thanks

Comment: Could you accept one of the answers please, or state why they are unsuitable or incomplete?

Comment: Usually, the wrinkles in leather apparel give each garment a distinctive and individual character. Some people pay extra for that appearance.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar situation, I had gloves, I simply let them suspend in bright sunlight for a day, in afternoon worn them and again let them in light.

They were dewrinkled and came in shape.

Answer (score 0):

this might help:

a friend from Germany says the car drivers over there who have enough money to buy leather upholstery for their cars like to use HAND MOISTURIZER CREME to condition their leather seats. This makes the leather more soft & flexible, but darkens it slightly especially if the leather is worn.

Once you rub on the conditioner, put on the jacket and wear it on a sunny day so it will warm up and get flexed, this will help work out the wrinkles and creases.

Answer (score 0):

I used Nikwax to do this. Check with a camping shop or Army/Navy store.

Put it in an airing cupboard to get it nice and fluid, and rub it in with a soft cloth. Don't slosh lots in, repeated applications alternated with spells in the airing cupboard on a hanger to help the creases drop out should work